# cron job or task scheduling in portable standard

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks, portability

i need to update/ empty my databases on a specific date. i've made it manually to be done by the admin. but if due to some reason, admin fails, then database won't be updated.

for doing this automatically, i've read about cron jobs or windows task scheduling.
but my project is under development now and i can't upload it to any site so that i can ping the specific page from other sites. my project is in USB, and i need to take to work, home, to friends or to wherever i can have access to a system. so creating a cron job or task schedule will not help as OS/ system is not constant.

how can i create a portable task scheduling?

or is there any other process to run the specific script and re-run after intervals whenever the server starts running?

i'm using xampp 1.8.2 in a USB under windows.

Comment: sure, make a script that creates a file/database entry with a timestamp in it or on it and every time a page loads if that timestamp has expired run your script and update the timestamp.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey 
it will always depend on a page request that it'll be run only when the (suppose) first page was requested. isn't there any other automatic process just like the cron jobs? so that the database can be updated on the time-stamp before the first request is made to the server after the time stamp.